# Bootstrap col-sm-offset not getting applied in small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap v 3.0.3. Bootstrap's offsets aren't working for me.

Here is a relevant example :

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2-popup col-md-4 col-md-offset-4-popup">
   ....
</div>
```

In small devices, `col-md-offset-4-popup` gets applied instead of `col-sm-offset-2`.

Anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: It happens because corresponding media query gets applied. Check in developer tool at what boundries it happens and compare with your devise screen width.

Comment: I am checking it right here http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ - 768 x 1024 (iPad - Portrait)

Comment: In all sizes it is applying `col-md-offset-4-popup`.

Comment: It's not clear why you use `col-md-offset-x-popup` instead of `col-md-offset-x`.

Comment: I get the same result after `removing popup`..... This code is in a dialog box... thats why i specified `popup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-md-offset-x-popup` doesn't exist in Bootstrap framework. In fact, there's not a single class containing the `popup` keyword. If it's a custom class, be sure it won't interfer with Bootstrap base classes.

As Bootstrap is mobile first, here's what you should use :

- `col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2` for extra small devices
- nothing more for small devices (will keep `-xs` values)
- `col-md-4 col-md-offset-4` for medium devices
- nothing more for large devices (will keep `-md` values)

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   ...
</div>
```

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/113292)

Answer (score 2):

What is a `'-popup'`?

If you want move columns to the right using `.col-md-offset-*`classes without `'-popup'`.
For example `<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3"></div>`

Comment: Check the comments following the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `col-xs-offset-*` with other classes in your div tag